# php not sending response of html form in email

Tags: php, html, email

I uploaded this php file on server and i want that when a user fills the html form present in this php file the user response should send to the email address that i mentioned in this php file .... but its not sending the response to the email address ... please help ... thank you

```
<?php 

if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 

$ToEmail = 'abc@gmail.com'; 

$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 

$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 

$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 

$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 

$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 

$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"]).""; 

mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die 

("Failure"); 

?> 

  Your message was sent

  <?php 

  } else { 

?> 

<form action="test.php" method="post">

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">

<tr>

<td width="29%" class="bodytext">Your name:</td>

<td width="71%"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="32"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td class="bodytext">Email address:</td>

<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="32"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td class="bodytext">Comment:</td>

  <td><textarea name="comment" cols="45" rows="6" id="comment"      
    class="bodytext">

     </textarea></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

  <td class="bodytext"> </td>

 <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="Submit"     

   value="Send">

  </td>

 </tr>

 </table>

  </form> 

  <?php 

  }; 

  ?>
```

Comment: So what exactly happens? Does it die ? Or does it display the "sent" message, but the mail doesn't come?

Comment: when i click on submit button it displays message " your message was sent" but when i check the my email account there is no such email

Comment: Is it a shared hosting? Or is it your server? Is it linux or windows? It is not guaranteed that `mail()` will send the email. it has to be configured properly to do it

Comment: I am using OOOwebhost and i m using it in windows

Comment: You should probably ask them then. windows systems have to have specific mail servers installed and configured so php could send mail with them. also consider using third party mail servers connecting to them via SMTP using PHPMailer class for example

Comment: Check you junk/spam boxes 99% your email is there..., I would also try to send plain text email

Comment: You obviously  change this abc@gmail.com to your email right?

Comment: @talsibony yes and there in no mail in spam/ junk

Comment: Is this the first time you sending email from the server? check your php.ini file for the mail configuration

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the email to the varible you defined earlier, `$ToEmail`. Change the value of that varible to the value you have from your form.

Try:

```
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 

$ToEmail = $_POST['email']; 

$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 

$mailheader = "From: abc@gmail.com\r\n"; 

$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 

$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 

$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 

$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."";
```

Comment: Thank you ... i edit my code with yours but its still not sending email ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using $mailheader = "From: admin@yourdomain"; for example email from asd.com must have $mailheader = "From: noreply@asd.com"; somilarly email from stackoverflow.com must have $mailheader = "From: admin@stackoverflow.com"; for authentic email sending. In some cases invalid email header causes failure to send email.

Comment: In my case should i write $mailheader = "From:abc@gmail.com"; ???

Comment: please see update in above.